# How to use AngularJs NgIf in front end html?

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, ionic-framework

In my case ( item.senses["0"].definition) , sometimes the json file dont have this data back. So i want to set Ngif on this part.Can anyone help me how should i write my code ? If this div has this json data, then show the data, else print null not something in the div.

```
  <ion-header>
      <ion-navbar color="primary" >
        <ion-title>

        </ion-title>
      </ion-navbar>

    </ion-header>

    <ion-content padding>


      <div class="headword">{{ item.headword }}
      </div>
      <div class="ipa"> {{ item.pronunciations["0"].ipa }}
        <ion-icon name="volume-up" class="sound">British</ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="volume-up" class="sound">American</ion-icon>
      </div>

      <ion-item>

        <ion-row>
          <p class="type"> [ {{ item.part_of_speech }} ]

        </ion-row>
      </ion-item>


      <div padding>
        <div class="Title">Definition : </div>
        <div class="Content">{{item.senses["0"].definition}} </div>

        <div class="Title">Example : </div>
        <!-- <button ion-button clear class="sound" (click)="playExample()">
    <ion-icon name="volume-up"></ion-icon></button> -->
        <div class="Content">{{item.senses["0"].examples["0"].text}} </div>

      </div>




    </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do with,

```
 <div ng-if="item.senses[0].definition" class="Content">{{item.senses["0"].definition}} </div>
 <div ng-if="!item.senses[0].definition" class="Content"> Nothing </div>
```